# Notifications problem, notify-osd is deleted

Tags: filesystem, notification

recently i installed *noise player*. it shows in a window song is the currently in played. I didn't like it. That's why I deleted the file ***notify-osd*** at **/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/**.

The noise's window has disappeared, but all notifications too.

how I can restore it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall `notify-osd` package again using the command in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install notify-osd
```

It will restore the file.

And for God's sake, don't delete random files here are there without knowing what that file's responsibility is. You will fall into trouble

Comment: Thanks. And it wasn't randomly, I saw it at system monitor. whatever thank you.